# Best approach to write xml element in jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have the next xml structure binded to a java object using jaxb:

```
    <my_object>
      <config>.....config parameters</config>
      <data>
         <type>a_type</type>
         <values>1.43321, 3.23344, 2.5666</values>
      </data
    </my_object>
```

My java object receives values generated in real time by another object in this way:

```
myObject.getData().getValues().add(1.1154);
```

and is neccesary to marshal to the xml element when the object has N new values.

I have readed that I can marshall only Double values, but I don't know how exactly achive this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "have readed that I can marshall only Double values", can't understand what you mean.. what do you like to achive?

Comment: I try to save the last N values stored in a array java object to an xml element.

Comment: Perhaps you show some Java code that does everything except the marshalling? This can be added easily, but without a starting point it's just a shot in the dark.

Comment: Maybe can I use json framework to achieve this? Petter, I want to have something like a BufferedWriter but only for the values element in the xml file. I wonder if somebody guide briefly in frameworks or concepts to implements this, not many detail is needed.